# Navigation from sap simple calendar to sap planning calendar

Tags: calendar, navigation, sapui5

My requirement is that I need to create a simple sap.ui.unified calendar and once I click on a particular date in the calendar,it should navigate to a SAP Planning calendar which should give the meeting details for the particular day alone.I have created the sap.ui.unified calendar and a seperate sap planning calendar.Iam unaware of how to navigate to a particular date's event in planning calendar on click of a date in smple calendar. Can anyone help me how this can done?I have used the "select" event for the calendar.But it selects the whole calendar.Can anyone provide code of how an event can be applied to a particular date for a calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for single date selection ([api](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.Calendar.html#getSingleSelection)) of class sap.ui.unified.Calendar:

```
getSingleSelection();
```

After event select (which you used) is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected date from the calendar with the method `oCalendar.getSelectedDates()`.
There is also an example in the [OpenUI5 Explored](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.unified.sample.CalendarSingleDaySelection/preview) on how to get the selected date.